# How to build different custom forms for each product type?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want customers to fill a form for each product and that forms have to be changed by product types. I searched it but i think i'm not using correct words for extensions. Is there any extension for this? (Of course, free extensions prior) Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a little more. what are those forms? how do they affect the checkout? What happens to the data the user fills in?

Comment: Those forms have to sent me by e-mail. They'll have information about product. For example, what's the name of groom? (for an invitation card)

Comment: @Marius any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webforms-pro-2-form-builder.html I have used before and its good..

```
<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'simple' ): ?>
//your code for simple products only
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( $_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped' ): ?>
//your code for grouped products only
<?php endif; ?>
```

Use above code to filter product types.